# getting Manager's email ID from LDAP?

Tags: java, ldap

I am trying to get a person's Email ID as well as his/her manager's email ID. And the following is the code I tried.

```
DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(LDAPDetails());
String[] attrIDs = {"sAMAccountName", "cn", "title", "mailnickname", "mail", "manager", "department", "telephoneNumber"};
    SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();
    ctls.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);
    ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    String filter = "(CN=285263)";
    NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ctx.search("OU=users,DC=cts,DC=com", filter , ctls);
    answer = ctx.search("OU=xyz,DC=cts,DC=com", filter , ctls);

   while (answer.hasMore()) {
   SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) retEnum.next();
   Attribute mailAttribute=sr.getAttributes().get("mail");
   System.out.println("Team Member's eMail: "+mailAttribute.get()); //Here I am able to get the person's email.
   Attribute managerAttribute=sr.getAttributes().get("manager"); // this is just getting the manager's CN value. Not the email ID.
   }
```

Can someone help me get the manager's email ID please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should search once again for the manager's email, once you get his CN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to lookup the manager(s) to get his (their) email address(es):

```
DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(LDAPDetails());
String[] attrIDs = { "sAMAccountName", "cn", "title", "mailnickname", "mail", "manager", "department", "telephoneNumber" };
SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();
ctls.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);
ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
String filter = "(CN=285263)";
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ctx.search("OU=users,DC=cts,DC=com", filter, ctls);

while (answer.hasMore()) {
    SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) retEnum.next();
    Attribute mailAttribute = sr.getAttributes().get("mail");
    System.out.println("Team Member's eMail: " + mailAttribute.get()); // Here I am able to get the person's email.
    Attribute managerAttribute = sr.getAttributes().get("manager"); // this is just getting the manager's CN value. Not the email ID.

    // now lookup the manger
    NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> managerAnswer = ctx.search(managerAttribute.get(), "", ctls);
    while (answer.hasMore()) {
        SearchResult managerSr = (SearchResult) retEnum.next();
        Attribute mailAttribute = sr.getAttributes().get("mail");
        System.out.println("Managers eMail: " + mailAttribute.get()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not a plain CN value. It gives like the following. 
CN=Jack Bobbins,OU=Users,OU=TCO,OU=City,OU=Country,OU=APAC,OU=xyz,DC=cts,DC=com

Comment: Then it should be even easier. You should be able to do a second lookup with the value from the members "manager" attribute. I changed the code.

Comment: After removing the crap, I made it a plain CN value and did search again, which worked beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach...

1..Connecto to LDAP

2..Search the user and Get manager name

3.. Search the LDAP with the manager name and object class as user in filter condition.

NamingEnumeration answermanager = context.search(managerAttribute.get().toString(),"(objectClass=user)",searchCtls);